# new install of 16.04 boots 3.13.0-96 despite the fact it isn't even present on any mounted filesystem

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

A fresh installation of 16.04 from the mini.iso. After the basic installation I used apt-get to install xorg, openbox, thunar and so on, set some groups, and reset the tty font. No DM. No DE other than Openbox itself. I'm using LILO because the OS-prober bugs that affect grub2 were such a nightmare in a system with lots of installed OSs, including some on external media that might or might not be present. I'll go back to grub2 when I'm just short of suicidal desperation, so let's not go there if we can avoid it.  I've seen discussions of similar problems with grub2 also, but none of the solutions worked for me. This seems to be an example of a common class of similar problems with 16.04 specifically. LILO works fine for 3 installations of variations of 14.04 and a Win something (7 I think - I only booted it a time or 2), but on a new installation of 16.04 it boots showing a pleasantly large, multicolored font in tty7 and hangs after this output:
"started update UTMP about system runlevel changes"
Sometimes before, sometimes after that, there will be the output
"getty@ttyN.service" where N is an integer from 1 - 6, inclusive.
I'm not sure N is consistent. Sometimes this message is repeated with other values of N, the other integers from 1-6. I think that's only if I access those ttys with cntrl-alt-FN. Maybe 16.04 is trying to start an x session even though I haven't told it to yet and for some reason fails at this step. Would that account for it being focused on tty7, while what looks like a normal non-graphical boot is taking place in tty1?
Anyway, after that hangs, I find in tty1, what appears to be, as far as I can tell, the end of a normal non-graphical boot process, with a login prompt. I can login normally. Startx works normally. It didn't at first but that was because ~/.Xauthority was owned root:root, which I fixed. In fact, everything I've checked seems to work pretty normally except it's the wrong kernel. I've confirmed this with both:
uname -r
&
cat /proc/version
.
The oddest thing is that 3.13.0-96 isn't present anywhere I'd expect this sytem to be able to access. Mount shows only the / partition mounted. Fstab only tells it to mount that one partition. I'm not useing a swap or a boot partition. /boot contains only the 4 series kernels you'd expect. So unless it is hiding it somewhere else in the filesystem, it must be mounting one of the other partitions long enough to at least read the 3.13.0-96 kernel, but mount doesn't show that.
At one point I thought this was because I had some sytems using a common boot partition and others using a boot directory and that this was confusing LILO, specifically meaning the lilo command, which reads /etc/lilo.conf, and apparently resolves the symlinks like vmlinuz in the root directories of filesystems and stores whatever their target is somewhere. I assume that because I have entries pointing at the symlinks in addition to some pointing at specific kernels and the ones that point at the symlinks don't work after a kernel update until I run lilo, and then they work.
Anyway, I changed that, changed all the fstabs, copied the stuff in the boot partition to the boot directories on the systems that needed it, deleted the boot partition, ran lilo, and everything works fine on the 3 14.04s but still the 16.04 boots the 14.04 kernel.

This is about the eleventy-seventh time I've installed 16.04. If nobody has the solution to this, I may try once more, and check out in detail how it behaves before I install anything. But I'm about ready to give up on it. Thanks for reading. Any ideas would be appreciated. Even half-baked ones, because I've run through all my reasonable and half-baked ideas and am working on raw ones. <|;-)

= = = = = = =

Update:

Some places like this, people set great store by "points" or some such, and answering your own question is regarded as cheating, or rude. So, I'm not doing that. What's the custom here??
Anyway, I solved this. So often articulating a problem clarifies your thinking on it, and I guess that is what happened. So, am I supposed to tell, for the benefit of people finding this from a search engine? Or leave it for someone to score points with? Or wait 24 hours or something?

Comment: It would help if you shortened and broke down that wall of text into easily "digestible" paragraphs. The title sounds like I can help you but I, like many people here (and elsewhere), can't be bothered to read paragraphs as long as the one in the current edition of your question unless they have a good incentive.

Comment: The 3rd and final paragraph is the only part that's still relevant. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) Shoot me a comment if you want an up-vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I misunderstood the syntax of lilo.conf.
The paths specified in each stanza are NOT relative to root of the filesystem given as root. They are relative to the root of the filesystem containing the installation with the effective lilo.conf. Whichever OS is "in charge" of lilo in other words.

Specifically, they are the paths in effect AT THE MOMENT the command "lilo" is run, regardless of whether the mount point is something in fstab or something arbitrary and temporary. So for example, if you mount another system's root as "/mnt/othersys" and then run the command "sudo lilo", the paths for the stanza for the other sys, need to begin with "/mnt/othersys/". If the next time you update a kernel, you mount it differently, for example as "/mnt/ubuntu1604", and you fail to change lilo.conf to reflect this, it won't work. If the paths happen, as in my case, to point somewhere that there is a file matching the kernel  name (as in may case, I was pointing them back toward the root of the filesystem containing the OS that I was booted into since I thought they were relative to the specified root, and running "sudo lilo" on, with the targets being the symlinks in /) it will APPEAR to succeed, but the boot info stored will be pointed at the wrong kernel and image.

All of which is because the command "lilo" finds the physical location (or what passes for it on a modern drive that refuses to make the OS privy to its inner workings) of the image and kernel files specified in terms of the filesystem mounted at the time the command was run, and stores those PHYSICAL (again, not really, but at any rate in terms only the HD's inner mechanisms can translate) locations, not paths/filename locations. So actually lilo.conf, as far as I can see, does nothing in between runs of the command lilo. The info needed in booting is stored somewhere else. Lilo.conf is just a guide to lilo in the generation of that info.